# Junit 3 to JUnit 4 conversion

Tags: java, junit4, testcase, junit3

I had the following version of a test in JUnit 3, and I tried converting it into JUnit 4, with no success. The idea is to have a base test case, that does the actual test of an interface, say `Service` interface. I want to test the `ServiceImpl` class, using the base test case.

```
public abstract class ServiceBaseTest extends TestCase {

   protected Service service;
   protected abstract Service getService();

   @Override
   public void setUp() {
      service = getService();
   }

   public void testMethod(){
      //test code
   }
   ...
}
```

`ServiceImplTest` class like:

```
public class ServiceImplTest extends ServiceBaseTest {
   @Override
   public void setUp() {
      service = new ServiceImpl();
   }
}
```

I am aware that I can remove the `TestCase` extension and use @BeforeClass for the `setup` method. But the difference is that `@BeforeClass` requires the method `setup` to be `static`. This is tricky for me,since I can't make `getService()` static, because it would be conflicting with `abstract` keyword.

`Question:` Is the a clean way of implementing the alternative, using JUnit 4?

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use the @Before annotation?

Comment: @Before will execute before each @Test. I just want to setup the Service once.

Comment: in JUnit3, setUp() is also called before each test. If you want to ensure that getService() is only called once, you can store the result of the call in a static field

Answer (score 1):

```
protected static Service service = null;

@Override
public void setUp() {
   if(service == null)//Check null
      service = new ServiceImpl();
}
```